# Angular 2 Arrow function not working in IE 11

Tags: angular

I am using arrow functions in my angular 2 project. IE produce some unusual behavior on loading.In chrome and Firefox it works fine. Does IE support Arrow functions?

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.subscribeAssignment().subscribe(
        (parameter) => {
            this.notification.userId = parameter.supervisorID;
            this.consultantNotification = true;

        },
        (error: any) => {
            console.log('Error ::' + error);
        });

}

<div *ngIf ="consultantNotification" class="notification"> contents...</div.
```

This arrow function is executing fine but the flag is not binding with html. All browsers except IE is working

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please improve your question. What is "unusual behavior". What code does cause this behavior? What behaviro do you expect?

Comment: I'm using ie11 and edge and have no problems with '() => '

Comment: @JohnBaird Please check the code. I'm using signalR library for notification. This arrow function is executing fine but the flag is not binding with html. All browsers except IE is working

Comment: Can you please post the code of `subscribeAssignment`?

Comment: Fixed, In IE the changes are not detecting (ie template binding not updating). So using the angular ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() we can able to re-render the html.